# Admin role global filter with Role and AllowAnonymous overrides?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorize-attribute

I've set up a global filter to require login for all methods based on [Rick Anderson's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx). Now I want to go one step further and require all actions are authorized to "Admin" role only, unless overridden by the AllowAnonymous attribute in the article or by [Authorize(Roles="Staff")] which would then allow "Staff" AND "Admin" to access.

I've tried adding to the Roles in the LogonAuthorize attribute constructor:

```
    public LogonAuthorize()
    {
        this.Roles = "Admin";
    }
```

.. but this restricts all actions to Admin and I can't override with an Authorize attribute on an action.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out soon after :O

I created another authorize attribute:

```
public sealed class OverrideAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
}
```

and used this as a test in LogonAuthorize:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
        || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
        || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(OverrideAuthorize), true)
        || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(OverrideAuthorize), true);

        if (!skipAuthorization)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Now I just need to tag my whitelisted actions with OverrideAuthorize (or AllowAnonymous):

```
    [OverrideAuthorize(Roles = "Staff, Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So the LogonAuthorize attributre applies to all controllers and actions by default and requires role "Admin" but it only authorizes if AllowAnonymous or OverrideAuthorize are not defined.